# How can I delete partial contents of a cell in a column using pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

So I am attempting to edit an entire column cell by cell to change the column from something that contains integer and string to just the integer component. For example

one cell looks like:

```
3001234; textTEXT TextTeXTExt.TExt
```

I am using this command:

```
df2.columns[3] = df2.columns[3].map(lambda x: x.lstrip([5:]))
```

Ive also tried something like this:

```
df2.columns[3] = df2.columns[3].split([])
```

This is the error I get from ipython:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Actual column from data frame:

```
0                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
1                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
2                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
3                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx     
8                  667788; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
9                  55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
10                 55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
11                 55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
12                 33333; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
13                 333; xxx xxxxx @ xxx xxx 2 xxxx   
14                 9991; xxxx; xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx @ 2 xxx   
18                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10   
19                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10   
20                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10   
21                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10     
32                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0   
33                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0   
34                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0   
35                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0
```

This is the code I am running

```
    import pandas as pd 

    # import excel file 
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile("/home/PATH") 
    # create data frame from excel file on sheet 1
    df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx,'Sheet1')

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Card": df2})
    print(df.head())

    df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])
    print df.head()

    # delete columns not relative to us
    df2.drop(df2.columns[[0,5,10,11]],inplace=True,axis=1)
```

Comment: So, from this `3001234; textTEXT TextTeXTExt.TExt` you just want to keep this: `3001234`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['3001234; textTEXT TextTeXTExt.TExt', '1005678;  more text']})
print(df)
col1
0  3001234; textTEXT TextTeXTExt.TExt
1                  1005678; more text


digits = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+', str(x)))
print(digits)
0    [3001234]
1    [1005678]
Name: col1, dtype: object

df['col1'] = digits.str.get(0).astype(int)
print(df)
col1
0  3001234
1  1005678

print(df.dtypes)
col1    int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: 'code' digits = df2.columns[3].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+', str(x)))                                             AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: @DeonSaunders You said, you want to `edit an entire column cell by cell`. So, can you try `df2['your column name'].apply(...)`?

Comment: No that does not work. I keep getting an error about the key.

Comment: @DeonSaunders Can you post your data frame so we can figure out the problem?

Comment: Check the post I modified it a few times and keep getting errors. Every column is float even if it has text. Why?

Answer (score 0):

df2.columns[3] represents the column name and not the column contents. Column name does not have methods like map or apply. use df.iloc[:, column_number]  or df['column_name'] to get the contents of the column.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [u'11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx', 
u'11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx',   
u'11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx',   
u'11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx',     
u'667788; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx',   
u'55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx',  
u'55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx',   
u'55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx',   
u'33333; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx',   
u'333; xxx xxxxx @ xxx xxx 2 xxxx',   
u'9991; xxxx; xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx @ 2 xxx',   
u'1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10',   
u'1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10',   
u'1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10',   
u'1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10',     
u'1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0',  
u'1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0',   
u'1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0',   
u'1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0']

# make a dataframe from data as the first column
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': data})

print df.head()

#Here I use the  iloc to the get the contents of first column (0 th column), in your case, it will 3)
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])

# in your case it will be 
#df.iloc[:,3] = df.iloc[:,3].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])

print df.head()
```

results in

```
                                  col0
0            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
1            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
2            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
3            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
4  667788; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
     col0
0   11212
1   11212
2   11212
3   11212
4  667788
```

Comment: I tried your method and am getting an AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'apply'>>>>>df2.columns[3] = df2.columns[3].apply(lambda x: ''.join(i for i in x if i.isdigit()))
)

Comment: can you post part of your data? so that I can try it out.

Comment: re check. I just added an example data frame

Comment: I think you were getting "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'apply'>>>>>df2.columns[3] = df2.columns[3].apply(lambda x: ''.join(i for i in x if i.isdigit())) ) –" because df2.columns[3] does not represent the contents of the column but rather gives only the name of the column. the name of column which is a unicode object does not have any attribute 'apply'. To choose the contents of the column, u need to use iloc as shown in the latest edit.

Comment: I added in the actual code I am using. I think I am having issues because I am using an excel file. Sorry to bother you again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: what do u see when you  print df2.head() after you obain df2 from reading excel

Comment: the header plus the first 4 lines

Comment: what do u get if u put df2.iloc[:,0] = df2.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0]) after df2.head()

Comment: it runs yet that is not that column I need changed. When I change it to the proper index >> "df2.iloc[:,4] = df2.iloc[:,4].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[4])"<<
I get an error:::::: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If I change df2.iloc[:,4] = df2.iloc[:,4].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[4]) 
to >>>>    df2.iloc[:,4] = df2.iloc[:,4].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0]) I get>>>>>>   AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: df2.iloc[:,4] seems to be a column with floats. are u sure your text is in 4?, 0 is the first column, 1 for the second column 2 for third column ..etc.

Comment: I'm not new to this. The 4th column has string and integers yet for some reason it thinks it is float. The only columns with float are columns in the 10s and 20s

Comment: I thinks that all of my columns are float even if they contain string. Do you think it is because of the way I imported my excel file?

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.extract('(\d+)')
```